# Sublime REPL VirtualEnv No Window Console found

Tags: python, sublimetext3, virtualenv, sublimerepl

So I have installed on [my Windows 10]:

- Python3 Anaconda Distribution
- Sublime Text 3
- Sublime REPL
- Sublime Virtualenv

I am trying to get the **SublimeREPL python - virtualenv to work**. Currently having no luck.

The virtualEnv Repl closes out when I open it.

> tools -> SublimeREPL -> Python -> python - virtualEnv

The REPL pops up, then gives me this:

```
C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\config.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.config` package has been deprecated. You should import from traitlets.config instead.
  "You should import from traitlets.config instead.", ShimWarning)
C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\console.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.terminal.console` package has been deprecated. You should import from jupyter_console instead.
  "You should import from jupyter_console instead.", ShimWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py", line 52, in <module>
    embedded_shell.initialize()
  File "<decorator-gen-114>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_console\app.py", line 137, in initialize
    self.init_shell()
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_console\app.py", line 110, in init_shell
    client=self.kernel_client,
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_console\ptshell.py", line 252, in __init__
    self.init_prompt_toolkit_cli()
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_console\ptshell.py", line 404, in init_prompt_toolkit_cli
    self.pt_cli = CommandLineInterface(app, eventloop=self._eventloop)
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\interface.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.output = output or create_output()
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\shortcuts.py", line 114, in create_output
    return Win32Output(stdout)
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\terminal\win32_output.py", line 80, in __init__
    info = self.get_win32_screen_buffer_info()
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\terminal\win32_output.py", line 150, in get_win32_screen_buffer_info
    raise NoConsoleScreenBufferError
prompt_toolkit.terminal.win32_output.NoConsoleScreenBufferError: No Windows console found. Are you running cmd.exe?

***Repl Closed***
```

## Virtual Environment locations

I currently tried three locations for my virtual environment, none of which work.

**Project folder:**

> C:\users\joshu\documents\Code\Sentient-CNC

**Home Envs folder**

> C:\users\joshu\Envs

**SublimeREPL default venv volder**

> C:\users\joshu\ .venv

in my user settings I have python_virtualenvs_paths variable set:

```
    // Where to look for python virtualenvs
    {
    "python_virtualenv_paths": [
        "~\\Documents\\Code\\Sentient-CNC",
        "~\\.venv",  // venv.bash https://github.com/wuub/venv
        "~\\Envs"
    ]
}
```

I don't think it matters, but I switched the '/' to ' \ ' as a means to troubleshoot my issue but it did not change anything.

the console log does not generate any error when running this.

I've also tried first activating a virtual environment in terminal then running SublimeREPL but this doesn't change anything.

### Path information

[image: System variables]

**from Cygwin:**

```
joshua@Josh-Laptop ~
$ which python
/cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/python

joshua@Josh-Laptop ~
$ where python
C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:\cygwin64\bin\python
```

**from cmd:**

```
C:\Users\joshu>where python
C:\cygwin64\bin\python
C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\python.exe

C:\Users\joshu>which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow finally got it to work... unfortunately I cannot explain the mechanics, but here are the steps I used:

in the cmd terminal, use conda create to make a virtual environment in my Anaconda package:

```
conda create venv
```

in Sublime Text 3, navigate to the SublimeREPL Package settings, and add the path to the Anaconda conda virtualenv folder:

```
// Where to look for python virtualenvs
{
"python_virtualenv_paths": [
    "~\\Anaconda3\\envs"
]
```

}

When you choose python - virtualenv from the sublimeREPL Menu, you should be able to select your virtual environment you created earlier and REPL should load it in and work.